# Microsoft Graph Access Token contains wrong permission for contacts API

Tags: azure, api, permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

So basically I need to access the contacts of an office 365 user.
I use the Microsoft graph API and I successfully can get all the contacts via an HTTP GET in a JSON. But now I'm trying to write a JSON to the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts API with an HTTP POST, but I get a 403 - Permission Denied every time. So I went to https://jwt.io/ and checked my access token and saw that I don't have the permissions to write in the contacts.

I get those permissions:

"scp": "Contacts.Read openid profile User.Read"

Even though I only set Contacts.ReadWrite in the App Registration settings on the Azure portal.

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVBJh.png)

I've tried updating the permissions but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have changed the permissions, users need to consent again.

[image]

You can force user consent through a url request, append &prompt=consent to the authentication request URL.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your_client_id}
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&state=12345
&prompt=consent
```

Or you just grant consent on behalf of all users in this directory. Granting admin consent for all users means that end users will not be shown a consent screen when using the application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but even after 17 hours, it still doesnt work. I found out that if I view my user and go to: Applications -> Assignment Detail -> Permissions & Consent. It says that I only have 4 Permissions for  that application, which are "Contacts.Read openid profile User.Read", so no matter what I choose in the API permissions on your screenshot, I will always end up with only those 4 permissions, do you know how to change these? The Graph Explorer got all the permissions for some reason, but my custom API doesnt give me the permissions even though I created it

Comment: Well, I tried that, when I went on the URL you sent me with my credentials, I get an error that I couldnt sign in because "AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application." I didnt create a reply address because I dont need it in my case

Comment: @lorenzg Then your application isn't a web app? You can add a httlps://localhost as the reply address to have a test. Or you can try with the admin consent in azure portal.

Comment: I just set the default "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient" as Redirect URI, so it worked for some reason (even though it just showed a blank screen, but I didnt get the Error that I mentioned before)! Thank you! Now it replaced the permissions and gave me the Contacts.ReadWrite Permission, that I needed.

Comment: @lorenzg Glad to hear that.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate it. Have a great day!