# How to reset API permissions Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing something using Microsoft Graph. 
At first, just some permission is given.
But I found it's not enough. I added more permission.
But it seems it's not working. Because after I log in, the Authorization web doesn't come out

I'm following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth) to use Microsoft Graph. and I'm using ADv1

I've added "User.ReadBasic.All".

I'm trying to get information by "/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName".
The error is as below

```
BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity(): 500 ERROR - [object Object]
botFrameworkAdapter.ts:607
(node:1752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [object Object]
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.processActivity (c:\Users\XXXXXX\src\botFrameworkAdapter.ts:608:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
warning.js:18
(node:1752) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
warning.js:18
(node:1752) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered. What specific permissions have been granted? What is the error message? Please embed the connection code in the answer.

Comment: sorry. I`ve just updated it

Comment: After updating the permissions, users and/or admins will have to consent again. Have you done it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3wY7.png

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent for more details.

Comment: @CaiyiJu Do you mean click the button of "Grant admin consent for XXX"?
Even when permission doesn't need admin authorization?

Comment: @Jeff_hu Correct.

Comment: @Jeff_hu Then the users in the tenant will not ask for consent again. If you don't want this, you can grant user consent again through a URL request. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your_client_id}
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&state=12345
&prompt=consent` Login with the specific user.

Comment: @Jeff_hu You can refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895445/10504999

Comment: I see. Thank you. answer my question. I will choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the permissions, users and/or admins will have to consent again.

Click 'Grant admin consent for XXX' to grant **admin consent**.

[image]

Force **user consent** through a url request

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id={your_client_id}
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
&state=12345
&prompt=consent
```

Refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent) for more details.